# How do I assign a string value to System.Windows.Forms.Keys?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I need to set **System.Windows.Forms.Keys** to a string that I have assigned.

I am using a 3rd party .Net control that lets me assign the HotKey to the control, and it uses **System.Windows.Forms.Keys** to set the HotKey.  For example: 
`this.systemHotKey1.SetHotKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.S); //Assign S as the HotKey`

However, System.Windows.Forms.Keys will not let me assign a string to it, I need to assign an actual value to it.  For example this works fine:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Keys.S (for the hotkey S on the keyboard).
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
{
string tmpString = "S";
this.systemHotKey1.SetHotKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.tmpString);  //This does not work
}
```

Can someone please show me a way I can assign a string to System.Windows.Forms.Keys so I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using KeysConverter

```
string tmpString = "S";
KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
this.systemHotKey1.SetHotKey(kc.ConvertFromString(tmpstring));
```

Comment: I get an error when I do this:  Argument type 'object' is not assignable to Parameter type 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' for the line of code that reads "kc.ConvertFromString(tmpstring)"

Comment: Have you tried cast it to Keys type ?this.systemHotKey1.SetHotKey((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)kc.ConvertFromString(tmpstring));

Answer (score 3):

I think you are after the [KeyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.aspx) in namespace System.Windows.Input

```
KeyConverter k = new KeyConverter(); 
Keys mykey = (Keys)k.ConvertFromString("Enter"); 
if (mykey == Keys.Enter) 
{ 
    Text = "Enter Key Found"; 
}
```

Since Keys is an enum you can also parse it like any enum.

```
string str = /* name of the key */; 
Keys key; 
if(Enum.TryParse(str, true, out key)) 
{ 
    // use key 
} 
else 
{ 
    // str is not a valid key 
}
```

Comment: Key key; does not work for me.  Do I need to import a namespace to use "Key"?

Comment: Updated, should be Keys. My bad sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will do the work:

```
KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();

string tmpString = "S";
Keys key = (Keys)kc.ConvertFromString(tmpString);
this.systemHotKey1.SetHotKey(key);
```

Comment: Cannot cast expression of type 'string' to type 'byte'