# Sending System.Windows.Forms.Keys to multiple regions/locales

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendmessage

All-

I've been trying to search and find a solution for a while but I'm still stumped on 2 questions

1)  Basically lets say I have this key:

System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A

And I want to send it using SendMessageto a window where the keyboard layout could be ANYTHING.  It could be US-EN, or DE, or BE, anything.

How can I achieve this?  Right now the windows are interpretting the key differently based on their regional settings.

I thought maybe KeysConverter but I don't see a function that would help with this.

2)  Lets say I just have a list of keys, how can I convert them to the correct codes (virtual?) to pass to SendMessage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you KNOW what the current keyboard layout is? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Sounds like there might be a easier way to do whatever you are trying to do...

Comment: May have found an answer to my 2nd question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312068/how-do-i-assign-a-string-value-to-system-windows-forms-keys

Comment: @Blachshma So I don't always know, but in theory I could read this from the operating system right?  I don't know how to do this (I've read sometimes you can use CurrentCulture but that doesn't always work)